# Using FontSelector to change font family

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery font selector plugin posted here

http://www.fullfatcode.com/2011/04/10/jquery-font-selector-version-2/

It's all good, except, I want to do something when the actual font is selected. At the moment the plugin is called via

```
$('input.font').fontSelector();
```

I guess what I'd like to be able to do is, capture the event when the font is selected and then do something. Maybe

```
$('input.font').fontSelector(function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```

Here's what I have been playing with

http://jsfiddle.net/d7nQV/1/

I tried

```
$('input.font').keyup(function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```

But it doesn't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little modified version: http://jsfiddle.net/cbkvs/

Comment: Very nice. :) And I was able to get the actual value of the input simply by $('input.font').val(). Thank you!